# Global Exception Handling using Middleware not working in ASP.Net Core app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, exception, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-middleware

I had been trying to set up **Global Exception Handling using custom Middleware** in my ASP.Net Core web API. I need to log them to a log file using **Serilog**. I tried a lot, but I'm not able to get it to work. I hope my friends here can help me.

### My Custom Middleware :

```
    public class ExceptionHandlingMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly ILogger<ExceptionHandlingMiddleware> logger;

    public ExceptionHandlingMiddleware()
    {

    }

    public ExceptionHandlingMiddleware(
        RequestDelegate next,
        ILogger<ExceptionHandlingMiddleware> logger)
    {
        _next = next ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(next));
        this.logger = logger ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (context is null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        }

        try
        {
            await _next.Invoke(context);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await HandleExceptionAsync(context, ex);
        }
    }

    private async Task HandleExceptionAsync(
        HttpContext context,
        Exception exception)
    {
        try
        {
            int statusCode = 0;

            if (context is null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
            }

            if (exception is null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(exception));
            }

            this.logger.LogError(exception.ToString());

            CustomApiResponse<CustomApiErrorResponse> errorResponse = null;

            if (exception is MyException myExceptionInfo)
            {
                statusCode = myExceptionInfo.StatusCode == default ? (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError : myExceptionInfo.StatusCode;
                errorResponse = new CustomApiResponse<CustomApiErrorResponse>()
                {
                    StatusCode = statusCode,
                    TraceId = context.TraceIdentifier,
                    Response = new CustomApiErrorResponse()
                    {
                        Message = myExceptionInfo.ErrorMessage,
                        StackTrace = myExceptionInfo.StackTrace
                    }
                };
            }
            else
            {
                statusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
                const string message = "Unexpected error";
                errorResponse = new CustomApiResponse<CustomApiErrorResponse>()
                {
                    StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError,
                    Response = new CustomApiErrorResponse()
                    {
                        Message = message,
                    },
                    TraceId = context.TraceIdentifier
                };
            }

            var responseContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(errorResponse);

            context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            context.Response.StatusCode = statusCode;
            await context.Response.WriteAsync(responseContent);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this.logger.LogError(ex.ToString());
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

---

### **Startup.cs**

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILogger<Startup> logger)
    {
        //app.UseExceptionHandlerMiddleware();

        app.UseExceptionHandler(new ExceptionHandlerOptions
        {
            ExceptionHandler = new ExceptionHandlingMiddleware().InvokeAsync,
        });

        //app.UseExceptionHandler(options =>
        //{
        //    options.Run(async context =>
        //    {
        //        // Exception Handling Code
        //    });
        //}
    }
```

Where am I going wrong? Is there anything else I need to do to get it to work? The exceptions get thrown from the code but is not caught by the middleware. Please do help me friends.

### Update

I'm using GraphQL instead of REST. So there are no controllers in my app. Is that a reason for this issue?

Comment: Hi @Arjun D Nair, `I'm using GraphQL instead of REST. So there are no controllers in my app. Is that a reason for this issue?` I think so. I test in api controller. It works well.

Comment: Hi @Rena, Thanks for the support. I too had referred couple of my old projects done using REST. In those projects it works fine but not in this one.

Comment: Hi @Rena, Seems like using GraphQL is the issue. I too tested it with a REST API sample project and it worked fine. Now I need to figure out why it is not working in GraphQL and how I can make it work. Anyway thank you for sparing some time for me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `ExceptionHandlingMiddleware.cs` is in the `Middleware` folder.

And use below in your configure method:-

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseMiddleware<ExceptionHandlingMiddleware>();

           ...
```

It will resolve your issue.if still not works,let me know.

Comment: Hi Pritom, I tried as you said. My Middleware was located in a class library project in my solution. I moved it to my main API project where the Startup.cs file is located and renamed the folder to Middleware and changed the namespace too. Still it doesn't seems to work.

Comment: @ArjunDNair can you show me your project folder directory picture?

Comment: Sorry bro it is a copyrighted project.

Comment: @ArjunDNair I actually just want to see your startup file, Middleware folder and its exception class location.

Comment: it's a location problem I guess.i want to makesure.if it's not location problem i will update your exceptionshandaling class code.

Comment: My exception class is in another class library project. Should I move that to the same project where the middleware is located? Will that fix the issue?

Comment: Your exception class should be in the Middleware folder and this middleware folder should be located where your startup.cs file

Comment: Okay @Pritom, I'll test as you said and let you know.

Comment: Hi @Pritom, I tried the same Exception and Middleware in another REST API project and it is working fine. Seems like the middleware is not working because I'm using GraphQL instead of REST in my project and hence I'm not using API controllers to create endpoints. Need to figure out another way to make it work while using GraphQL. It worked even with the Exception and Middleware in another class library project.

Answer (score -1):

Try changing your startup like this:

```
app.UseMiddleware<ExceptionHandlingMiddleware>();
```

instead of

```
app.UseExceptionHandler(new ExceptionHandlerOptions
{
    ExceptionHandler = new ExceptionHandlingMiddleware().InvokeAsync,
});
```

Comment: I had tried that too. Still it doesn't seem to work.